# .NET library for use with XBRL or XLINK

Tags: xlink, xbrl

Does anyone know of a good .NET library I can use to process XBRL or XLINK documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gepsio: XBRL Document Object Model for .NET](http://gepsio.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for [Altova XML library](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) instead

Answer (score 1):

There is the [GEPSIO](https://gepsio.codeplex.com/) Open Source project.
However, GEPSIO doesn't support all XBRL specifications, just XBRL 2.1 (and even this seems incomplete).

There is another commercial XBRL .NET API available at that supports all specifications: The [AMANA XBRL Engine](https://amana-consulting.de/en/xbrlengine.html)

Please see official list of "Tools and services" on xbrl.org.